# How to dynamically change part of a link url?

Tags: asp.net

I have a live site (mysite.com) and a dev site (dev.mysite.com) which is an exact copy of the live site.  I am trying to redirect the dev site's absolute links so that I STAY on the dev site.  Currently, of course, clicking those links takes me to the live site- which doesn't help me test. I'm fairly new to asp, but after some research I came up with something for my Global.asax.cs file that I *thought* would work- but it doesn't. Here's what I tried:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.ToString();
    string endOfPath = Request.RawUrl.ToString();

    if (url.Contains("mysite")) {
        Context.RewritePath("dev.mysite.com" + endOfPath);
    }
}
```

The idea was that if you started at dev.mysite.com clicking a link would automatically insert "dev.mysite.com" onto the front of that link- replacing what was there for an absolute link or just prepending it to a relative link. Either way you'd stay on the dev site.

I get the feeling I'm over-complicating this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you change the way you generate the URL in the first place?  We use an entry from the application settings to append the value at the beginning of the link, rather than statically defining any links?

Comment: No, they're all hard coded links within various pages

Comment: Do you use plain anchor tag for links or HyperLink server control?

Comment: They're just plain anchor tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can include javascript below at the end of the master page or add ClientScript.RegisterStartUpScript method to base page class if you have any:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var host = window.location.host;
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for (var index = 0; index < links.length; index++) {
        if (links[index].href.search("__doPostBack") == -1 && links[index].href.search("javascript:"))
        {
            links[index].href = links[index].href.replace(host, host + "/dev.mysite.com");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly this script would run whenever the master page is loaded and rewrite the urls to add "/dev.mysite.com". Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

if you use iis 7.0+ (or iis express in visual studio) the easiest way is to use the url rewriting module with something like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
           <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
              <match url="(.*)" />
                 <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^dev.mysite\.com$" negate="true" />
                 </conditions>
                 <action type="Redirect" url="http://dev.mysite.com/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
         </rules>
   </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

obviousely this should only be included in the web.config of your dev site. If you have a previous version of iis an other url rewrite module is also available. With this approach you don't have to change any of the code in your site.

**EDIT:** I later realized that actually won't work, as it depends on iis having both incoming url's configured. You could try with a different url rewriting module / aproach. 
see here for more on url rewriting: 
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/